# WSO2is using roles

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I use WSO2 identity server, i can´t understand in documentation how works roles to my application (service provider), i understand the roles works for make changes into wso2 platform, but i don´t know how this help me to get roles and permissions to my app.

For example, i need it create a role with the name `writer` and other role `supervisor`, the role writer can edit and create new docs, but `supervisor` only can read docs and mark for edit by editors.

When i create this rol in wso2 and i have to mark permissions only can see permissions for wso2 management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions that you can see in the WSO2 management console are only to set the permission levels for WSO2 identity server functionalities.

If you need to implement any permission levels based on the user roles in your application side, it needs to be handled by yourself.

You can retrieve the available roles of the authenticated user to your application from the WSO2 identity server via a SAML response, an ID token, etc based on the authentication protocol that you use.

After that, you will have to implement the permission levels in your application side based on your requirements.

Comment: Thank for your anskwer, i trying using openid and claim the role user and I  using xacml for describe access based in roles and actions.